# Open Webview links in new navigation controller

Tags: ios, uiwebview

In Xcode I am trying for all links in a webview to open in a new navigation controller view. So that I can add it to the stack.

The new view can be exactly the same as the old but just needs to have the new link loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the UIWebViewDelegate in the controller.
Use the ...

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
   // Push here
   return NO;
}
```

... method, to get the new URL you want to push next.

Comment: Looks very promising, sorry to be a pain but do you have an example code to add for the push here part?